# How to set an event handler in builder delegate

Tags: blazor

---

I have a reusable thing like this, that creates a tree recursively:

```
public async Task Select(InstallationTree.TreeNode node)
{

}

private RenderFragment GetLevel(InstallationTree.TreeNode root) => AsLevel((root, this));

private RenderFragment<(InstallationTree.TreeNode node, LocationSelector self)> AsLevel = (prop)
        => __builder =>
        {
            foreach (var l in prop.node.ChildLocations)
            {
                <div class="row" @onclick=@prop.self.Select>                        
                    <div class="name col">@l.Name</div>
                    <div class="count col">@l.Count</div>
                </div>
                @prop.self.GetLevel(l);
            }
        };
```

Everything is great till I want to add the `onclick` to the row. Then I get a
`Error  CS0027  Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context.` in the generated file. Yes, I know that the signature is different, but does not matter what kind of handler I want to attach there, and `@onclick="() => prop.context.Select(l)"` gives the same error. In the context of that delegate `this` does not exist, which is true, that is why I had to add the wrapper method to pass it along.

How can I provide that handler?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not the nicest, but it can be achieved with combining this autogenerated and the imperative approach:

```
private RenderFragment<(InstallationTree.TreeNode node, LocationSelector self)> AsLevel = (prop)
        => __builder =>
        {
            foreach (var l in prop.node.ChildLocations)
            {
                __builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
                __builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "row");
                __builder.AddAttribute(2, "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create(prop.context, () => prop.context.Select(l)));
                    <div class="name col">@l.Name</div>
                    <div class="count col">@l.Count</div>
                __builder.CloseElement();
                @prop.self.GetLevel(l);
            }
        };
```

I changes a bit how the css isolation will work, but still...

The generated version would would have had `EventCallback.Factory.Create(this,...` and that causes the problem.
Isn't there any way to provide a context to the builder somehow?